# Appending first value of a list into the first value of another list; python

Tags: python, list, append

Working in python 2.7.

I have two lists (simplified to make explanations clearer).

```
T = [[1,0], [1,0], [0,5], [3, -1]]
B = [[1], [3], [2], [2]]
```

I would like to append the second list (B) so that the first value of the B list is appended to the first list in the T list and so on.

Ex- I want the output to look like:

```
T = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 3], [0, 5, 2], [3, -1, 2]]
```

I've tried playing around with different types of append functions, but I haven't found anything that works. Knowing python, I'm sure there's a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map(list.extend, T, B)
```

or, if you prefer an explicit loop

```
for t, b in zip(T, B):
    t.extend(b)
```

Comment: Using map should be faster, just for the record.

Answer (score 2):

Use [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> t = [[1,0], [1,0], [0,5], [3, -1]]
... b = [[1], [3], [2], [2]]
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(t, b)]
3: [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 3], [0, 5, 2], [3, -1, 2]]
```

Comment: This is a non-inplace version, which is not what was asked for but often a better idea.